# Laravel 5.2 : Upload multiple image with intervention but First image only uploaded

Tags: php, laravel-5, multifile-uploader, intervention

Hi I am trying to upload multiple images using the intervention package but when I start upload one image only gets upload

**here is the view**

```
{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'admin/event-gallery', 'method'=>'post', 'files'=>'true')) !!}
                {!! Form::label('image', 'Event Image Gallery') !!}
                {!! Form::file('image[]', ['multiple']) !!}
                {!! Form::hidden('event_id', $event->id) !!}
                {!! Form::submit('Add More Images', array('class'=>'btn btn-primary')) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**and here is the controller**

```
    public function store( Request $request ) {
                $event = new EventGallery();
                if ( $request->hasFile( 'image' ) ) {
                    $images = $request->file( 'image' );
                    foreach ( $images as $image ) {
                        $event->event_id = $request->event_id;
                        $filename        = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                        Image::make( $image )->resize( 450, 150 )->save( 'images/events/' . $filename );
                        Image::make( $image )->fit( 243, 111 )->save( 'images/events/thumbs-' . $filename );
                        $event->image = $filename;
                    }
                }
$event->save();
    Session::flash( 'status', 'Event has been added successfully' );

            return Redirect::to( 'admin/events/create' );
        }
```

**Edit on how I got it work**

1. First it was the `save()` outside the `foreach` loop.
2. Second I had a very strange issue here when I done with upload I found the images duplicated, and this was cased by this part of the code `$filename        = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();` it was because the `time()` so don't trust the `time()` when you are uploading multiple files here I replaced it with `str_random( 10 )` and every this was OK after that.

if anybody have any comments or suggesting will be happy to hear from him.

Comment: I got it it was the save `$event->save();` outside the `foreach`